# SPL Token `createMint` returns "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')"

Tags: spl-token

I want to use the `createMint` function in '@solana/spl-token'.

I don't want to use `Keypair.generate()` when I call a function.

Here is my code:

```
export const createToken = async () => {
  const wallet = Keypair.generate();
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
  await connection.requestAirdrop(wallet.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
  const mint = await createMint(
    connection,
    wallet._keypair,
    wallet.publicKey,
    null,
    9,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  );

  console.log(mint.toBase58());
};
```

This code returns undefined 'toString'. I don't know why it returns undefined.

I've already tried 'wallet._keypair' and 'wallet'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `createMint` is missing a few parameters.

The signature for `createMint` is:

```
export async function createMint(
    connection: Connection,
    payer: Signer,
    mintAuthority: PublicKey,
    freezeAuthority: PublicKey | null,
    decimals: number,
    keypair = Keypair.generate(),
    confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions,
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): Promise<PublicKey>
```

> I dont want to use Keypair.generate() when I call a function.

You can pass in undefined, so the default value will be used.

Your call should look like this:

```
  const mint = await createMint(
    connection,
    wallet,
    wallet.publicKey,
    null,
    9,
    undefined,
    {},
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // optional, can be omitted
  );
```